# How do I run this line from cmd as a bat?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this command line that I type in cmd all the time and I want to automate it as a .bat file

```
E:\Programas\Steam\steamapps\common\Victoria 2>v2game -mod=mod/NameMod.mod
```

I tried several variations of this:

```
echo off
start "E:\Programas\Steam\steamapps\common\Victoria 2\v2game.exe -mod=mod/NameMod.mod"
```

But either I can't open the program or it doesn't load the tag that I want in the end.

I'd appreciate it if you tell me what's the correct synthaxis. Thanks!

Comment: `start` expects the first quoted string to contain a window title. Remove `start` entirely from the command. For more info about `start`, use `start /?` from a command prompt.

Comment: Why do you think you need `start` in a batch file while you do not need it in Command Prompt?